# Sharing Folder In A Specific Group

Tags: networking, network-share

Good morning, can someone help me on my problem? Windows Server 2008, and 16 PC, in windows server I g create a 4 group, and I add specific users into a group,. I shared a folder in windows server, and I want only group 1 can access in that folder, I already make the steps in sharing folder, but it doesn't work, still I can't access the folder...

Answer (score 1):

You had to enable read/write permissions in two different places:

- on the share itself ('sharing' tab)
- on the files/directories via NTFS access list ('security' tab)